# Storing data in HBase using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I am trying to store data in HBase using the following code:

```
val x = Seq((1, ("a", "A")), (1, ("a", "AA")), (2, ("d", "D")), (2, ("d", "DD")))
val f = sc.parallelize(x)
val z = f.groupByKey()

z.collectAsMap().foreach(elem => {
    var rowKey = elem._1.toString()
    var p = new Put(rowKey.getBytes())

    elem._2.foreach(innerElem => {
        var col = innerElem._1
        var value = innerElem._2
        p.add("cf".getBytes(), new String(col).getBytes(), new String(value).getBytes())
        table.put(p)
    })
})
table.flushCommits()
```

I am getting the following output from hbase shell:

```
ROW        COLUMN+CELL                                                                                   
 1         column=cf:a, timestamp=1487917201238, value=AA                                                                                                 
 2         column=cf:d, timestamp=1487917201226, value=DD
```

But I want to get:

```
ROW        COLUMN+CELL 
 1         column=cf:a, timestamp=1487917201238, value=A                                                                                  
 1         column=cf:a, timestamp=148791720123X, value=AA                                                
 2         column=cf:d, timestamp=1487917201226, value=D                                                 
 2         column=cf:d, timestamp=148791720122X, value=DD
```

My code is overriding the first value of a specific column and just storing the last value of that column. I want to store every value of a specific column.

When I moved `var p = new Put(rowKey.getBytes())` into the second foreach loop in scala shell I got the following:

```
scala>     
     |  z.collectAsMap().foreach(elem => {
     |       val rowKey = elem._1.toString()
     |        
     |       elem._2.foreach(innerElem => {
     | Display all 620 possibilities? (y or n)
     | ew Put(rowKey.getBytes())
     |         var col = innerElem._1
     |         var value = innerElem._2
     |         p.add("cf".getBytes(), new String(col).getBytes(), new String(value).getBytes())
     |         table.put(p)
     |       })
     |     })
<console>:49: error: not found: value ew
       ew Put(rowKey.getBytes())
       ^
<console>:52: error: not found: value p
               p.add("cf".getBytes(), new String(col).getBytes(), new String(value).getBytes())
               ^
<console>:53: error: not found: value p
               table.put(p)
                         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the scope of `Put` object. Think about it as a hashtable. You just override the values on the second `forloop` iteration. Create separate `Put` objects in every iteration and it'll be fine.

Comment: Could you please guide me to create separate Put objects. I am naive in coding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Moved var p = new Put(rowKey.getBytes()) into second foreach loop but it shows error: not found: value: new Put(rowKey.getBytes()).

Comment: I added the snippet in to my question.

Comment: as far as I can see you forgot about var p = new

Comment: The line `var p = new Put(rowKey.getBytes())` becomes `| Display all 620 possibilities? (y or n)
     | ew Put(rowKey.getBytes())` in scala shell when I paste the code.

Comment: I have created a jar by moving `var p = new Put(rowKey.getBytes())` inside second foreach loop but it is still overriding the previous value for a particular column. Could not keep both values for the same column name.